# How to use Gyroscope in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, gyroscope, core-motion

I'm trying to use apples provided code in my project to record the gyroscope data into a variable I can use. Currently, this is what I have got to. I'm unsure how to copy the gyro data into a variable I can use outside of this class or even print the value. I'm not sure if it is even starting. Any help would be seriously appreciated.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreMotion


class ViewController : UIViewController {

    let motion = CMMotionManager()
    var timer = Timer()
    var GyroVar = 0
    var gyroData: CMGyroData?

    func startGyros() {
        if motion.isGyroAvailable {
            self.motion.gyroUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 60.0
            self.motion.startGyroUpdates()

            // Configure a timer to fetch the accelerometer data.

            self.timer = Timer(fire: Date(), interval: (1.0/60.0),

            repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
// Get the gyro data.
                if let data = self.motion.gyroData {
                    let x = data.rotationRate.x
                    let y = data.rotationRate.y
                    let z = data.rotationRate.z
                    print("gyro works")
            // Use the gyroscope data in your app.
                }
                print("outloop")
            })

      // Add the timer to the current run loop.
            RunLoop.current.add(self.timer, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
        }
    }


    func stopGyros() {
        print("stop")
        if self.timer != nil {
            self.timer.invalidate()
            self.motion.stopGyroUpdates()
   }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you said

```
let x = data.rotationRate.x
let y = data.rotationRate.y
let z = data.rotationRate.z
```

you can print any of these or use a label

For example,

```
print("this is x:", x)
print("this is y:", y)
print("this is z:", z)
```